# Why is the centered moment for this formula so different?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, variance, quadratic-forms

Define the following two functions $Q$ and $S^2$:
[image]

One of the exercises now asks me to calculate the variance of $S^2$. I tried doing so with the help of a formula that makes use of the third and fourth centered moment and as far as I know, the fourth moment of a normally distributed variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma ^2$ is $3\sigma ^4$. In the solution; however, the author writes the following:

[image]

**My question now is: Why would that be the case? From what does this follow?** Both parts here are quite confusing to me; I don't see why it would be equal to $3\mu _2 ^2$ or equal to $3\sigma^2$ instead of $3\sigma ^4$.

(Source: Seber, 2003, Linear Regression Analysis)

Comment: Looks like a typo. When the second central moment $\mu_2$ is the variance $\sigma^2\,.$ Its square times three can impossibly be $3\sigma^2\,.$